# Showing the existence of separating hyperplanes using the Hahn-Banach theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, convex-analysis, hahn-banach-theorem

I am trying to show the existence of separating hyperplanes for points $v$ outside of any compact, convex, equilibrated set $X \subseteq V$ that contains $0$ in its interior. I know that since $X$ has these properties, a norm $\nu_X: X → \mathbb{R}$ with unit ball $X$ can be defined by $\nu_X(x) = \inf\{\alpha > 0 | \frac1\alpha x ∈ X\}$. So $\max\{\nu_X(x)|x \in X\} = 1$, then by the Hahn-Banach theorem, $\nu_X$ can be extended to a linear functional on $V$ whose maximum magnitude on the unit $\nu$-sphere in $V$ is $1$. Since $v \notin X$, then $\nu_X(v) > 1$, so $\nu_X(v) > \nu_X(x)$ for all $x \in X$, which implies the existence of a separating hyperplane. Is my work correct? I feel like I never really used the Hahn-Banach theorem. Can someone explain why exactly I need Hahn-Banach? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> then by the Hahn-Banach theorem, $\nu_X$ can be extended to a linear functional on $V$

The Hahn-Banach theorem definitely doesn't say that, because no such linear functional exists.  You can see this from the fact $\nu_X \geq 0$ on a neighborhood of $0$, and the only linear functional $f$ satisfying $f \geq 0$ in a neighborhood of zero is $f=0$.

---

Instead, the proof usually follows these steps:

1. Since $X$ is a compact, convex, balanced neighborhood of $0$ [plus necessary assumptions on the real topological vector space $V$], there is a norm $\nu_X$ on $V$ such that $X = \{x \in V : \nu_X(x) \leq 1\}$
2. For $v \in V \setminus X$, define a linear functional $f_v : \mathbb{R}v \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f_v(tv) = t\nu_X(v).$  Note that $$|f_v(tv)| = |t\nu_X(v)| = |t|\nu_X(v) = \nu_X(tv)$$ so in particular $|f_v| \leq \nu_X$ and $f_v(v) = \nu_X(v)$.
3. By Hahn-Banach, there is a linear functional $g_v : V \to \mathbb{R}$ extending $f_v$ such that $|g_v| \leq \nu_X$.

With that setup, we can conclude, for all $x\in X$, $$g_v(x) \leq \nu_X(x) \leq 1 < \nu_X(v) = g_v(v)$$
from which we can find a separating hyperplane.

Comment: Thanks for your correction! I just have some clarifying questions. 1. Is the $v$ in the last inequality from $V \setminus X$ or the point from which I'm trying to find the separating hyperplane? 2. Why can't we just use $\nu_X(x) \le 1 < \nu_X(v)$ to show the existence of a separating hyperplane?

Comment: 1.  Yes.  Throughout, $v$ is a particular point in $V \setminus X$.  It's the same one you're trying to separate from $X$ using a hyperplane.  2. If $f$ is a continuous linear functional, then $\{x : f(x)=c\}$ is a hyperplane.  Here $\{x : \nu_X(x)=c\}$ is not a hyperplane.  Note that we do technically use $\nu_X(x) \leq 1 < \nu_X(v)$ to show the existence of a separating hyperplane, but the way we do this is Hahn-Banach; it doesn't give us a hyperplane by itself.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification! I thought an element of $V\setminus X$ is a subset of $V$ while the particular point $v$ is an element of $V$. By "same" do you mean they are isomorphic? Also, could you clarify a bit about the notation "$\mathbb{R}v$"? Does it mean $t \in \mathbb{R}$? Sorry for the confusion. I am new to advanced linear algebra.

Comment: I don't know what notation you're imagining (maybe a quotient $V / X$ in some sense?).  In any case, an element of $V \setminus X$ is an element of $V$ which isn't an element of $X$, or symbolically $$V \setminus X = \{x \in V : x \not\in X\},$$ so by "same" I mean it's literally the same point. --- As for $\mathbb{R}v$, it's the span of the vector $v$.  That is, $\mathbb{R}v = \{tv \in V: t \in \mathbb{R}\}$

Comment: I see! It occurs to me that I confused the set minus sign with the quotient symbol. Thank you very much for your generous help!